# Bootstrap Datetime picker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap date time picker. my problem is my code isnt able to fetch Am/Pm. I have tried:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
        sideBySide: true,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm tt'

    });
```

bUt this is only giving me, time as, 09:23 tt. it is showing tt in place of am and pm.

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a' instead, or '...A' for capital AM/PM.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 5):

According to  moment.js docs you can use 'DD/MM/YYYY h:mm:ss a'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm P",
 showMeridian: true
```